# How can I import urlparse in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, urlparse

I would like to use `urlparse`, but Python 3 is not finding the module.

I do `import urlparse`, but it gives me this error

```
ImportError: no 'module' named urlparse
```

Answer (score 91):

The urlparse in Python 2.7.11 was renamed to urllib.parse in Python 3.
So, if you have a code such `from urlparse import urljoin`, I suggest you change it to `from urllib.parse import urljoin`

Answer (score 57):

As noted in [`urlparse`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html):

> **Note** The `urlparse` module is renamed to `urllib.parse` in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

I.e., just use `urllib.parse` instead:

```
import urllib.parse
```

Comment: how do i can install 2to3 tool and use it?

Comment: @MohamedMahdi it's provided by the `python3-tools` rpm. Once installed, just run `2to3 myscript.py`.

Comment: i fount the 2to3 file in python34/tools/scripts and i run it. it gave me " at least on file required. then i wrote this command " 2to3 myscript.py, but it told me that it can't open myscript.py as there is no such a file or directory!