# Error with command import when running script

Tags: python

getting the error:

```
import urlparse, ssl
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urlparse'

in

import urlparse, ssl

sorry, new in stack overflow, anyone got some idea on how to fix?
thankyou

finding something online, could't find it

Comment: urlparse was renamed `urllib.parse` in python3 so you need to do `import urllib.parse` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072619/how-can-i-import-urlparse-in-python-3